# How to concatenate strings to form a json object in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-10

I have a string `coldata->>'f1'` which I need to send dynamically to fetch JSON object.

What I want exactly is:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'OBJECT %', fc_data->'firstname'->>'value';
```

In my case I am getting the `firstname` dynamically in the variable `coldata->>'f1'` in my stored procedure. I need to send the key dynamically to get the value. For which I tried the below code:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'OBJECT %', ((('fc_data->')::text) || '''' || ((coldata->>'f1')::text) || '''');
```

Which is displaying `fc_data1->'firstname'`, this is being considered as string by Postgres and I want the value of it. So I tried converting it into `jsonb` as below:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'OBJECT %', ((('fc_data->')::text) || '''' || ((coldata->>'f1')::text) || '''')::jsonb;
```

It is giving me the below error:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
> DETAIL:  Token "fc_data" is invalid.
> ```

How do I concatenate the string as key to the object?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No it is 10.11

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have tried something and got a part of it. I just need to make text to json

Answer (score 0):

The [`->` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) for `json` / `jsonb` takes `text` or `int` to the right, which can come from an expression. You can simply:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   coldata jsonb := '{"f1":"firstname"}';
   fc_data jsonb := '{"firstname": {"value":123}}';
BEGIN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'OBJECT %', fc_data -> (coldata->>'f1') ->> 'value';
END
$do$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c5f74ff20955b2598e83e0ecba09ec34)*
(I made it an exception in the fiddle, wo we get to see it.)

Just to add parentheses like demonstrated.